# HDFS: Using HDFS API to append to a SequenceFile

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've been trying to create and maintain a Sequence File on HDFS using the Java API without running a MapReduce job *as a setup* for a future MapReduce job.  I want to store all of my input data for the MapReduce job in a single Sequence File, but the data gets appended over time throughout the day.  The problem is, if a SequenceFile exists, the following call will just overwrite the SequenceFile instead of appending to it.

```
// fs and conf are set up for HDFS, not as a LocalFileSystem
seqWriter = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf, new Path(hdfsPath),
               keyClass, valueClass, SequenceFile.CompressionType.NONE);
seqWriter.append(new Text(key), new BytesWritable(value));
seqWriter.close();
```

Another concern is that I cannot maintain a file of my own format and turn the data into a SequenceFile at the end of the day as a MapReduce job could be launched using that data at any point.

I cannot find any other API call to append to a SequenceFile and maintain its format.  I also cannot simply concatenate two SequenceFiles because of their formatting needs.

I also wanted to avoid running a MapReduce job for this since it has high overhead for the little amount of data I'm adding to the SequenceFile.

Any thoughts or work-arounds?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Support for appending to existing `SequenceFiles` has been added to Apache Hadoop 2.6.1 and 2.7.2 releases onwards, via enhancement JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7139

For example usage, the test-case can be read: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.7.2/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/TestSequenceFileAppend.java#L63-L140

CDH5 users can find the same ability in version CDH 5.7.1 onwards.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, currently the Hadoop FileSystem does not support appends. But there are plans for it in a future release.

Comment: Haha, that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Is that still true? It sounds like CDH3 at least makes this doable?