# Writing to HDFS : File is overwritten

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am writing to hadoop file system. But everytime I append something, it overwrites the data instead of adding it to the existing data/file. The code which is doing this is provided below. This code is called again and again for different data. Is opening a new SequenceFile.Writer everytime a problem?

Each time I am getting the path as new Path("someDir");

```
  public void writeToHDFS(Path path, long uniqueId, String data){
      FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
      SequenceFile.Writer inputWriter = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf,
          path, LongWritable.class, MyWritable.class);
      inputWriter.append(new LongWritable(uniqueId++), new MyWritable(data));
      inputWriter.close();
  }
```

Comment: I don't see the use of a sequencefile when you just put a record into it and directly close it. Keep the file open and constantly append.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to append to an existing SequenceFile through the API.  When you make the new `SequenceFile.Writer` object, it will not append to an existing file at that `Path`, but instead overwrite it.  See my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598400/hdfs-using-hdfs-api-to-append-to-a-sequencefile).

As Thomas points out, if you keep the same `SequenceFile.Writer` object, you will be able to append to the file until you call `close()`.

Comment: What if I have too many paths to write to randomly? Can I keep lots of SequenceFile.Writer open?

Comment: Since `SequenceFile.Writer` does not have a flush method, all of its contents will be in memory until you close them.  So, keeping a lot of Writers open will not scale.  It may make sense to create a MapReduce job using the `SequenceFileOutputFormat` to construct your SequenceFiles if the problem lends itself to MapReduce.

Comment: Can FSDataOutputStream be used for writing key value? Will writing key.getBytes{space}value.getBytes{newline} be similar to SequenceFile.Writer's append?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems possible.  You can look at the source for SequenceFile.java to see how it uses `FSDataOutputStream`.

Comment: I did it by not closing the writer until the writing was done. Thanks.