# Why does SequenceFile writer's append operation overwrites all values with the last value?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, sequencefile

First, Consider this CustomWriter class:

```
public final class CustomWriter {

  private final SequenceFile.Writer writer;

  CustomWriter(Configuration configuration, Path outputPath) throws IOException {
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
    if (fileSystem.exists(outputPath)) {
      fileSystem.delete(outputPath, true);
    }

    writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(configuration,
        SequenceFile.Writer.file(outputPath),
        SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(LongWritable.class),
        SequenceFile.Writer.valueClass(ItemWritable.class),
        SequenceFile.Writer.compression(SequenceFile.CompressionType.BLOCK, new DefaultCodec()),
        SequenceFile.Writer.blockSize(1024 * 1024),
        SequenceFile.Writer.bufferSize(fileSystem.getConf().getInt("io.file.buffer.size", 4 * 1024)),
        SequenceFile.Writer.replication(fileSystem.getDefaultReplication(outputPath)),
        SequenceFile.Writer.metadata(new SequenceFile.Metadata()));
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    writer.close();
  }

  public void write(Item item) throws IOException {
    writer.append(new LongWritable(item.getId()), new ItemWritable(item));
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is consume a asynchronous stream of `Item` type objects. The consumer has a reference to a `CustomWriter` instance. It then calls the `CustomWriter#write` method for every item it receives. When the stream ends, the `CustomWriter#close` method is called to close the writer.

As you can see I've only created a single writer and it starts appending to a brand new file. So, there is no question that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962802/writing-to-hdfs-file-is-overwritten) is not the cause.

I should also note that I am currently running this in a unit-test environment using `MiniDFSCluster` as per the instructions [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToDevelopUnitTests). If I run this in a non unit-test environment (i.e. without `MiniDFSCluster`), it seems to work just fine.

When I try to read the file back all I see is the last written `Item` object N times (where N is the total number of items that were received in the stream). Here is an example:

```
sparkContext.hadoopFile(path, SequenceFileInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, ItemWritable.class)
    .collect()
    .forEach(new BiConsumer<>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(Tuple2<LongWritable, ItemWritable> tuple) {
        LongWritable id = tuple._1();
        ItemWritable item = tuple._2();
        System.out.print(id.get() + " -> " + item.get());
      }
    });
```

This will print something like this:

```
...
1234 -> Item[...]
1234 -> Item[...]
1234 -> Item[...]
...
```

Am I doing something wrong or, is this a side effect of using `MiniDFSCluster`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Writable` (such as `LongWritable, ItemWritable`) is reused during processing data. When receiving a record, `Writable` usually just replaces its content, and you will just receive the same `Writable` object. You should copy them to a new object if you want to collect them into an array.